# Can I parse XML data using Java's SAX after a 400 error?

Tags: java, android, url, sax

I'm using an API that returns a 400 error on a bad request and it includes a status code in valid xml with a nice explanation. Currently I'm using an `InputStream` obtained from `URL` and passing it to a `SAXParser` but this doesn't work when I get the 400 because `URL.openStream()` throws a `FileNotFoundException`. Is there anyway I can still obtain that stream from the `URL` and parse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really depends on how you're making the connection.  If you're using java.net.HttpURLConnection you can make a method call to getResponseCode().  Likewise, getErrorStream() sounds like it would be useful to you too.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I just had to `openConenction` instead of `openStream`, then I can check the status codes as needed and use `getErrorStream`.